# Android ADT issues

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I've downloaded `adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219` for my Windows8, using SDK manager i've doawnloaded all the necessary tools.
The problem is when i open the ADT from Eclipse and i select the workspace, i see this message:

This android SDK requires Android Developer toolkit version 23.0.0 or above.
Current version is 21.1.0.2013-2-6-0-46
Please Update ADT to the latest version"

but when i click on "Check for Updates button"
and it is always "No updates were found"
then all my projects have the same errors,  the very first line from any project.
And when i try to add a new software it gives me this error "Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.

```
  Software being installed: Android DDMS 23.0.4.1468518 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.feature.group 23.0.4.1468518)
  Software currently installed: Android Developer Tools 21.1.0.201302060051 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 21.1.0.201302060051)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Common Android Utilities 23.0.4.1468518 (com.android.ide.eclipse.base 23.0.4.1468518)
    Common Android Utilities 21.1.0.2013-2-6-0-46 (com.android.ide.eclipse.base 21.1.0.2013-2-6-0-46)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: ADT Package 21.1.0.201302060051 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group 21.1.0.201302060051)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 21.1.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Developer Tools 21.1.0.201302060051 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 21.1.0.201302060051)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group [21.1.0.201302060051]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android DDMS 23.0.4.1468518 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.feature.group 23.0.4.1468518)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.base [23.0.4.1468518]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android DDMS 21.1.0.2013-2-6-0-46 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 21.1.0.2013-2-6-0-46)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.base [21.1.0.2013-2-6-0-46]"
```

i searched on internet but i found nothing, hope to get a help on this, thanks.

Comment: learn to format your post.

Comment: @almasshaikh : Perhaps instead of criticising a first post from somebody you might have edited and formatted their question...you have enough rep to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below link:
https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

This link is said to solve this problem for many.I tried the above link but I am getting some other problem.Please let me know if you got the solution.

Thanks